# Slot not being passed from action to layout in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, action, slots

I'm using the following to set a slot in an action but I can't retrieve it in the layout.

```
$this->getResponse()->setSlot('global_message', 'You have already completed this contest.');
```

But if you set this in the template file, it works fine.

Anyone have any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 2):

It should work. Please provide some code about your controller, view and layout.